# От чего зависит, с какого устройства пользователь будет онлайн при взаимодействии с API VK?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Отправляю я запрос VK API с токеном пользователя, например, метод [account.setOnline](https://vk.com/dev/account.setOnline).
Как узнать/установить, с какого устройства будет показан онлайн пользователя (Android/iPhone/ПК)?

Comment: "От чего зависит" - от id приложения, это работает только для официальных клиентов

Comment: @andreymal 
т.е. чтобы менять устройство, с которого пользователь онлайн, я должен брать разные токены официальных приложений?

Comment: @Vertonger, все верно

Comment: @Theartofbeingalive только что пробовал включать онлайн с разных клиентов через API
Во многих клиентах устройство, с которого будет отображаться онлайн = устройство, с которого получен access_token
Есть способы получать токен с телефона, но чтобы вк думал, что токен получен с компа, и  наоборот?

Answer (score 4):

Для этого нужно использовать метод [`users.get`](https://vk.com/dev/users.get), с указанием идентификатора пользователя и с параметром `fields` равным `online`. В результате будет показан статус онлайна, и идентификатор приложения, с которого пользователь находится в сети.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]